# What do I capitalize in this sentence?

Tags: capitalization, noun-phrases

I'm writing a paper about the lives of aristocratic women during the Heian period in Japan and I'm wondering about how to capitalize certain nouns in this sentence:

"In Heian japan, there were many famous books published but the most famous and well known of those books is, *Tale of Genji*, by Murasaki Shikibu."

When I say "Heian japan" I am refering to the time which what I am saying is occuring. Since I make Heian Japan a single noun phrase would only the first word of the noun phrase be capitalized, or should both?

Answer (score 2):

Your noun phrase contains two proper names *Heian* (named from Heian-kyō, the modern city of Kyōto) and *Japan* (the name of the nation).  Capitalize both proper names.